# Handle Auth0 invalid request

Tags: angular, auth0

I have enabled Auth0 based login for my app, which triggers `loginWithRedirect()` on `ngOnit()`.

I am looking to handle `/?error=invalid_request&error_description=no connections enabled for the client` this error message as every time this happens it refreshes the page and retriggers the login again and goes into infinite loop.